# Cannot past StringBuilder to another activity

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I want make application to get json from server, and set it into text view, but its always shown null pointer

```
try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code" + response);
            }
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String data = response.body().string();
                System.out.println(data);
                Intent kirim = new Intent(this, SuksesActivity.class);
                kirim.putExtra(datakirim, data.toString());
                startActivity(kirim);
                finish();
            }
```

This is my second activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tampil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc);
        setContentView(R.layout.sukses_activity);
        Intent kirim = getIntent();
        String datadapat = kirim.getStringExtra(MainActivity.datakirim);
        tampil.setText(datadapat);
    }
```

what wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` Exception in `SuksesActivity` Activity due to

```
   tampil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc);
    setContentView(R.layout.sukses_activity);
```

lines. Always access Views from layout using `findViewById` after setting layout for Activity by calling `setContentView`. Change it to:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.sukses_activity);
    tampil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc);
```

Comment: yeah thank you, it work now. i am not careful. @ρяσѕρєя K